# About the substitution theorem for power series ("Mathematical Analysis Second Edition" by Tom M. Apostol)

Tags: analysis, power-series

I am reading "Mathematical Analysis Second Edition" by Tom M. Apostol.

In the statement of Theorem 9.25, the author assumed that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |b_nz^n|<r.$
If we assume that $|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nz^n|<r$ for a fixed $z$ in $B(0;R)$, can we write $f[g(z)]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k z^k$?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and you can understand it without any calculations, from some properties of power series.

Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{1 - z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$, let $g(z) = \sin(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n + 1}}{(2n + 1)!}$.

Then $r = 1$ and $R = \infty$. Power series of $f(g(z))$ has radius of convergence at most of $\pi / 2$ (because this function has a pole at this point), and we know that power series diverges everywhere outside of it's convergence radius (because even common term doesn't go to $0$).

So, if we take say $z = \pi$, we get $|g(z)| < r$, but series for $f(g(z))$ diverges.

Comment: mihaild, Thank you very much for your clear answer.